# Applying upsert in Mongodb .Net driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to perform atomic "if not exist add" logic, else do nothing, to do this I am using Upsert.

My model:

```
  public class Person
  {
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedAt { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
  }
```

my code:

```
var person = new Person() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "name", Title = "title", ReceivedAt = DateTime.Now };
var result = context.People.FindOneAndUpdateAsync<Person>(
           x => x.Title == person.Title && x.Name == person.Name && x.ReceivedAt <= person.ReceivedAt + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
           Builders<Person>.Update.Combine(),
           new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Person>() { IsUpsert = true });
```

The above is not inserting the document is not exist, what I am doing wrong? do I need to set something other than IsUpsert?

Comment: ... in most ORM's you need to `SaveChanges`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but "If not exists, add, else do nothing" sounds like an insert, not an upsert (which is insert OR update). FindOneAndUpdate will do nothing if it doesn't find a match.

Comment: @Stefan it is automatic in .Net driver.

Comment: @DanielleSummers sounds like an assumption, "FindOneAndUpdate will do nothing if it doesn't find a match" then why I can pass IsUpsert value in options?

Comment: @YahyaHussein, my bad. I should stay off SO before I've had coffee. You are correct ,IsUpsert will insert the document if it doesn't exist. If you want the returned result to contain the new document, add "ReturnNewDocument = True" to the FindOneAndUpdateOptions.

Comment: Thank you but My issue is that the insert operation is not happening

Comment: `Builders<Person>.Update.Combine()` - nothing in Combine?

Comment: This should be for the fields I want to update, what if I don't want to update anything?

Comment: Then you should use `Builders<Person>.Update.SetOnInsert(x => x.Title, person.Title)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `result` is of type `Task<Person>` and you miss `await` here and that's why you don't observe that Exception is thrown. When you change your code to:

```
var result = col.FindOneAndUpdateAsync<Person>(
                   x => x.Title == person.Title && x.Name == person.Name && x.ReceivedAt <= person.ReceivedAt + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                   Builders<Person>.Update.Combine(),
                   new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Person>() { IsUpsert = true })
               .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // or await in front of invocation
```

You'll get an `ArgumentException` with following message:

> Additional information: Updates must have at least 1 update operator.

So you can't have empty update. To fix that you can for instance repeat `Title` property, which works exactly the same way as your code expects.

```
var result = col.FindOneAndUpdateAsync<Person>(
                   x => x.Title == person.Title && x.Name == person.Name && x.ReceivedAt <= person.ReceivedAt + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                   Builders<Person>.Update.Set(x => x.Title, person.Title),
                   new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Person>() { IsUpsert = true }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

`ReceivedAt` will not be added since your lambda expression translates to `$lte` which is not an equality comparison (check docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior)). You should explicitly define that value in update part.

> The update creates a base document from the equality clauses in the  parameter, and then applies the update expressions from the  parameter. Comparison operations from the  will not be included in the new document.

Comment: Thank you, but why I see only id, name, and title in DB? despite that person has values for receivedAt and Children  is not null.

Comment: @YahyaHussein modified my answer, `ReceivedAt` will not be added (explained why), I can't see anything related to `Children` in your code